# Оптимизация картинок без потери качества gem 'image_optim'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Для оптимизации картинок я нашел интересные гемы:

```
Gemfile
gem 'image_optim'
gem 'image_optim_pack'
```

Создал в application_controller.rb

```
def optim_img(img_path)
    image_optim = ImageOptim.new
    image_optim.optimize_image!(img_path)
end
```

Создал метод загрузки файлов по одному

```
#Загрузка файлов по одному
  def upload_one_by_one(params, folder="uploads")
    @files=[]
    params.each_with_index do |item, index|
      if item[0].include?("file_")
        uploaded_io = params[item[0]]
        #create uniq name
        uniq_name=SecureRandom.uuid
        ext=File.extname(uploaded_io.original_filename)
        #detect or create folder
        directory = 'public/images/'+folder
        Dir.mkdir(directory) unless File.exists?(directory)
        # create the file path
        path = File.join(directory, "#{uniq_name}#{ext}")
        # write the file
        File.open(path, "wb") { |f| f.write(uploaded_io.read) }
        filesHash={"src" => 'images/'+folder+"/"+"#{uniq_name}#{ext}", "id" => item[0]}
        resize_img('public/images/'+folder+"/"+"#{uniq_name}#{ext}", {"width" => 1920})
        #Пока смог сделать чтобы оптимизировало только .jpg, png оптимизация покане работает
        if ext == '.jpg'
          optim_img('public/images/'+folder+"/"+"#{uniq_name}#{ext}")
        end
        @files.push filesHash
      end
    end
    @files
  end
```

Метод работает при сохранинии картинок отосланных ajax post c использование angular.js
Вопрос:
В методе есть блок , но пока смог сделать чтобы оптимизировало только чтобы оптимизировались .jpg, .png оптимизация пока не работает, поэтому написал if ext == '.jpg', вообще хотелось бы убрать if но тогда, процессы rails при отптимизации просто зависают, раньше было ошибки нет PNGOUT, потом урок с youtube

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GljD3Z2a6xY  
if ext == '.jpg'
    optim_img('public/images/'+folder+"/"+"#{uniq_name}#{ext}")
end
```

Тем самым установил PNGOUT ошибка пропала, но картинки так и не получается оптимизировать + в случае если я убираю `if`
Т.е. я оставляю просто

```
optim_img('public/images/'+folder+"/"+"#{uniq_name}#{ext}")
```

картинку .png оптимизоровать не получается.
Ошибок в консоле rails нет.
Последнее что пишет консоль rails

```
Processing by AdminCategoryController#upload as HTML
  Parameters: {"file_1"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f62de349f48 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20150726-18917-glwk4u>, @original_filename="sprite.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file_1\"; filename=\"sprite.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">}
```

Но это помоему строка загрузки картинки.
Т.е. в методе

```
optim_img('public/images/'+folder+"/"+"#{uniq_name}#{ext}")
```

rails просто повисает и не пишет никаких ошибок, но дальше не работает, и оптимизировааная картинка не создается, точнее создается только для картинок формата .jpg, а для png не работает.
Может кто-то оптимизировал загружаемые картинки в `rails`, или попветуете что-то подобное `gem 'image_optim'`
в идеале что-то типа `https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-imagemi`n только на `ruby on rails`?

Comment: Пришло время для глубокой отладки :] Записывайте гемы в `development`: `pry-rails` и `pry-byebug`, опционально `pry-doc` и `pry-coolline`. Перед местом, где возникает ошибка, поставьте `binding.pry`, вызовите эту ошибку и пошарьтесь по консоли сервера посреди запроса. [Инструкции](http://pryrepl.org/).

Comment: Спасибо попробую